# Is there a way to sort a dictionary and keeping its keys?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have made an "`Enums`" class like this:

```
class PersonneEnums(object):
    LANGUE_ALBANAIS = 0
    LANGUE_ALLEMAND = 1
    LANGUE_ANGLAIS = 2
    LANGUE_ARABE = 3
    LANGUE_ARMENIEN = 4
    LANGUE_BENGALI = 5
    LANGUE_CATALAN = 6
    LANGUE_CHINOIS = 7
    LANGUE_COREEN = 8
    LANGUE_CROATE = 9
    LANGUE_DANOIS = 10
    LANGUE_ESPAGNOL = 11
    LANGUE_FINNOIS = 12
    LANGUE_FRANCAIS = 13
    LANGUE_GREC = 14
    LANGUE_HONGROIS = 15
    LANGUE_ITALIEN = 16
    LANGUE_MALAIS = 17
    LANGUE_MONGOL = 18
    LANGUE_NEERLANDAIS = 19
    LANGUE_OCCITAN = 20
    LANGUE_PERSAN = 21
    LANGUE_PORTUGAIS = 22
    LANGUE_ROUMAIN = 23
    LANGUE_RUSSE = 24
    LANGUE_SERBE = 25
    LANGUE_SLOVAQUE = 26
    LANGUE_SLOVENE = 27
    LANGUE_SUEDOIS = 28
    LANGUE_TURC = 29
    LANGUE_AUTRE = 30
    TAB_LANGUE = {
        LANGUE_ALBANAIS: _(u'Albanian'),
        LANGUE_ALLEMAND: _(u'German'),
        LANGUE_ANGLAIS: _(u'English'),
        LANGUE_ARABE: _(u'Arabic'),
        LANGUE_ARMENIEN: _(u'Armenian'),
        LANGUE_BENGALI: _(u'Bengali'),
        LANGUE_CATALAN: _(u'Catalan'),
        LANGUE_CHINOIS: _(u'Chinese'),
        LANGUE_COREEN: _(u'Korean'),
        LANGUE_CROATE: _(u'Croatian'),
        LANGUE_DANOIS: _(u'Danish'),
        LANGUE_ESPAGNOL: _(u'Spanish'),
        LANGUE_FINNOIS: _(u'Finnish'),
        LANGUE_FRANCAIS: _(u'French'),
        LANGUE_GREC: _(u'Greek'),
        LANGUE_HONGROIS: _(u'Hungarian'),
        LANGUE_ITALIEN: _(u'Italian'),
        LANGUE_MALAIS: _(u'Malaysian'),
        LANGUE_MONGOL: _(u'Mongolian'),
        LANGUE_NEERLANDAIS: _(u'Dutch'),
        LANGUE_OCCITAN: _(u'Occitan'),
        LANGUE_PERSAN: _(u'Persian'),
        LANGUE_PORTUGAIS: _(u'Portuguese'),
        LANGUE_ROUMAIN: _(u'Romanian'),
        LANGUE_RUSSE: _(u'Russian'),
        LANGUE_SERBE: _(u'Serbian'),
        LANGUE_SLOVAQUE: _(u'Slovakian'),
        LANGUE_SLOVENE: _(u'Slovenian'),
        LANGUE_SUEDOIS: _(u'Swedish'),
        LANGUE_TURC: _(u'Turkish'),
        LANGUE_AUTRE: _(u'Other'),
    }
```

When I add it into a form it's like this:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Personne
        fields = ('blablafields',)

    e = {'required': _(u'This field is required'),
         'invalid': _(u'This field contains invalid data')}
    a = _(u'Mother tongue:')
    langue = forms.IntegerField(
        label=a, required=True,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'title': a,
            'groupno': 2,
            'class': 'form-control', },
            choices=[('', '--')] + [(k, PersonneEnums.TAB_LANGUE[k])
                                    for k in PersonneEnums.TAB_LANGUE]),
        error_messages=e)
```

And the problem is that the form displays the choices "as is". I'd like the choices to be alphabetically sorted.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Read update. https://github.com/ambv/dj.choices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class PersonneEnums(object):
    LANGUE_ALBANAIS = 0
    LANGUE_ALLEMAND = 1
    ...
    TAB_LANGUE = OrderedDict((
        (LANGUE_ALBANAIS, _(u'Albanian')),
        (LANGUE_ALLEMAND, _(u'German')),
        ...
    ))
```

This way all your items will be ordered the way you put them in `TAB_LANGUE`.

And then you should use `.items()`

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Personne
        fields = ('blablafields',)

    e = {'required': _(u'This field is required'),
         'invalid': _(u'This field contains invalid data')}
    a = _(u'Mother tongue:')
    langue = forms.IntegerField(
        label=a, required=True,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'title': a,
            'groupno': 2,
            'class': 'form-control', },
            choices=(('', '--'),) + tuple(PersonneEnums.TAB_LANGUE.items()),
        error_messages=e)
```

**Update**
Also there is very cool third party django app called [dj.choices](https://github.com/ambv/dj.choices/). It is very helpful for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

how about this solution:

```
langues_classees =  sorted(PersonneEnums.TAB_LANGUE.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

`.items()` does exactly the same as `[(k, dictionnaire[k]) for k in dictionnaire]`

Also, if you ever need to interface this with any other language management tools at some point, you should use ISO language codes (e.g. ar for arabic, hy for armenian, en for english, zh for chinese, etc.) instead of coming up with your own codes

**UPDATE**:
The solution above may not be adapted to your use case, because you may want the sorting to happen at the time of the request and depend on the browser's language ('German' comes after 'Arabic' in English but in French, 'Allemand' comes before 'Arabe') rather than when the Form class is declared.

Check a solution for a "Lazy choice field" at https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1767/

Comment: It's not only about languages, I have 10 more fields like this (point of interest, personnality and so on so maybe I've taken the wrong sample to ask my question...) thank you very much for your answer